# Newbie Doesn't Get Unicorns

Tags: discussion

I am extremely confused about this unicorn game, my biggest question: Is this for real?

[image]
I think I'm suffering from shock, I could've sworn I never saw this before.
Is this new or what?

Comment: yes it's brand new ;)

Comment: It suddenly occurred to me that today was actually tomorrow, and that I need to stop staying up past midnight...

Comment: Great, totally not a joke, new feature! I have 35,000 rep now!

Comment: @Jeff I wouldn't be too sure of that...

Comment: We should close this question, because Unicorns!!!

Comment: @Woody There is no way that a simple game boosting my rep by 10x would be a joke, obviously serious..

Comment: COINS people. uniCOINS!

Comment: You're all drunk... go home. There's no such thing as... Unicoins?

Comment: Wait, must be legit, I have 27,000 reputation now! Muwhahahahaha!

Comment: Unicorn vote animations used to be free. I feel cheated.

Comment: This was a great April 1 joke.  Unfortunately when I went to click for a description of the powers it didn't list anything.  I would have liked to have seen the list.  While reading I was thinking, this is really odd, why are they doing this

Comment: I though it was an ad. . . Kinda stupid honestly, I have way too much rep to be seeing ads.

Comment: And the ad was sponsored by a mouse button manufacturer, obviously.

Comment: @MrLister Ah, so you've had a problem too I see

Answer (score 14):

Theres a day in the year that even unicorns are true. But seems that you already realized that. :D

Comment: well said dear friend, well said :)

Answer (score -3):

You guys are aware it's April Fool's Day?

Comment: Whose what? Is that some sort of American holiday?

Comment: -1, spoiler alert.

Comment: Unicorns a Joke???? Are you some kind of communist?

Comment: Wait, must be legit, I have 27,000 reputation now! Muwhahahahaha!

Comment: @MDTGuy Pssh, _only_ 27,000?  I'm at 467,480! ;)